# How to create an upload file field using react-final-form?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-final-form

I am trying to create an upload field ( class based ) using react-final-form

Strangely documentation does not contain any info regarding this. Is there any way to implement this?

I am getting a junk file link that is not useful to upload the file to the server.

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might want to consider using something like react-dropzone. I did mix it up with react-final-form in my last projects & it worked fine. I stripped it off the validation logic & some other extra stuff, & uploaded it for you [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-mirzakhani-c91ut?file=/src/FileField.js:0-1122). it's not class-based, but I hope you can work from here.

Comment: It's a real pain with that package. I ended up using default react with states to handle this which gives better control.

Comment: @user3697484 could you show an example thanks

Comment: that's not true. it only gets submitted after clicking the submit button. check your  console.

Comment: i think you should check your console in your sanBox, and you will see that when you click on "choose file", console print 'undefined' tha is the result of the submit of your form that has a console.log(),

Comment: ok. I see what you mean. it was because a type prop with the value "submit" was being passed to it from the parent by default, so an override of that to type="button" fixed it. . recheck the sandbox. it's fixed now. thanks for bringing it up

Answer (score 1):

also you might want to consider using something like
https://github.com/tim-mccurrach/react-final-form-file-field

Comment: this is not compatible with react 17